# Switching to apache user

Tags: server, apache2, lamp, webserver

Why I can switch to apache user using

```
su -s /bin/bash apache
```

But It's not permitted to do that using

```
sudo su apache
```

What's the difference between these commands?

Answer (score 4):

You can't switch to the user apache because in `/etc/passwd` it is set as a nologin user due to security risks. However you can run commands by this user using `sudo -u apache ./script`. And this means we can run shell as a command

Comment: Perfect! This is a great way to emulate how the server will behave when creating files such as log files or temporary files. The file ownership will be `apache:apache` which is what the file system is expecting, so avoids permissions issues during development. My current use case is Django: `sudo -u apache python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. If I run this command as any other user, any attempts to create files in folders that belong to `apache` (user or group) will fail. Means I can set `770` or `660` permissions instead of `777` or `666`. NICE